# how do i make a mdframed box appear in the table of contents like a subsection named "box1: mdframedtitle"

Tags: table-of-contents, mdframed

i have a mdframed box defined like

```
 \mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
frametitlealignment=\center,
    frametitlerulecolor= black,
    frametitlerulewidth=0.2pt
    outerlinewidth=0pt,
    repeatframetitle =false,
    frametitleaboveskip=15mm,
     frametitlebelowskip=5mm,
    frametitlefont={\sffamily\bfseries},
      topline=false,
  rightline=false,
  leftline=false,
  bottomline=false,
    roundcorner=20pt,
    splittopskip=\baselineskip,
    innertopmargin= 5pt\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!40!white}
```

i was wondering if there was a way to make its title appear among the paragraphs in the table of contents as "box 1: frametitle"  in italic font format.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sectioning commands call `\addcontentsline{<file>}{<kind>}{<title>}` to make an entry in `<file>` which is `toc` for the Table of Contents, `lof` for the List of Figures or `lot` for the List of Tables. `<kind>` is the kind of entry, for example `section` for a `\section`, and similarly `subsection` and so forth.

For your mdframedbox something like (untested)

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\textit{box1: mdframedtitle}}
```

at the appropriate place in your code.

Comment: thanks, it works.